# Foundation 5 Orbit slider skipping and stiking on small view

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm running into difficulties with Foundations Orbit slider on mobile and tablet views, when swiped with figure to the right the slides start to go then get a little stuck then they go to the next slide and so on, when swiped from right to left the slides and headline text get very messy, view website here: [kids toy site](http://bit.ly/1tgm6xp)

HTML

```
          <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">
            <ul class="orbit-content" data-orbit>




              <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
                <div class="large-5 medium-11 small-12 right columns insliderbox">
                  <h3>jigsaws</h3>
                  <p>New jigsaws in stock. Colourful animal shapes designed to teach children numbers and the alphabet.</p>

                  <a class="button slider-btn left" href="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/tales-by-tigerlily/featured-news/featured-news-test-post-three/" title="jigsaws">Click to find out more</a>
                </div>
                            <img src="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Kawaii-Slider_02.jpg" alt="slide image" />
              </li>

              <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
                <div class="large-5 medium-11 small-12 right columns insliderbox">
                  <h3>String Dolls</h3>
                  <p>String Dolls first appeared in Thailand over a decade ago. Since then they have been slowly making their way around the world.</p>

                  <a class="button slider-btn left" href="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/tales-by-tigerlily/featured-news/featured-news-test-post-two/" title="String Dolls">Click to find out more</a>
                </div>
                            <img src="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Kawaii_slide01.jpg" alt="slide image" />
              </li>

              <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
                <div class="large-5 medium-11 small-12 right columns insliderbox">
                  <h3>Socky Dolls</h3>
                  <p>Socky Dolls are a collectable range of heatable soft toys, made from real sock materials!</p>

                  <a class="button slider-btn left" href="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/tales-by-tigerlily/featured-news/featured-news-test-post-one/" title="Socky Dolls">Click to find out more</a>
                </div>
                            <img src="http://kawaii-1.hksn.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Kawaii-Slider_03.jpg" alt="slide image" />
              </li>
                        </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .content-slider h3 {
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1.1;
    }

    .content-slider {
        position: relative;
    }

    .orbit-slide-number, .orbit-timer {
        display: none;
    }
    .orbit-bullets-container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .orbit-bullets li {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f1f1f1;
    }
    .orbit-slides-container li {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .orbit-slides-container li div {
        padding: 2em 50px;
        position: relative;
        top: 4.5em;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .orbit-slides-container li img {
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 1282px;
        max-height: 432px;
    }

    .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > *  {
      height: 432px !important;
    }

    .orbit-container {
        min-height: 432px;
    }

    .insliderbox {
      background-color: rgba(240, 142, 10, 0.8);
      margin: 0 42px 0 0;
    }

    .insliderbox h3 {
      font-size: 2.2em;
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64.063em) {
      .insliderbox h3 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
      }
      .insliderbox {
        margin: 0 4% 0 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
      .content-slider {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .insliderbox h3 {
        font-size: 1em;
      }
      .insliderbox p {
        font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      .insliderbox {
        padding: 5px 10px 1px !important;
      }
      .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container img {
        display: block;
        max-height: 212px;
      }
      .insliderbox {
        margin: 0;
      }
    }

    .orbit-prev {
      background: url("../images/sprite-sheet.png") no-repeat scroll 2px -375px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .orbit-prev:hover {
      background: url("../images/sprite-sheet.png") no-repeat scroll 2px -454px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .orbit-next {
      background: url("../images/sprite-sheet.png") no-repeat scroll -9px -295px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .orbit-next:hover {
      background: url("../images/sprite-sheet.png") no-repeat scroll -9px -220px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    .orbit-container .orbit-next:hover,
    .orbit-container .orbit-prev:hover,
    .orbit-container .orbit-prev span,
    .orbit-container .orbit-next span {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border: none;
    }
    .orbit-container .orbit-prev, .orbit-container .orbit-next {
        margin-top: 17px;
        width: 50px;
        top: 35%;
    }

    .orbit-container {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .orbit-slides-container {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
    .orbit-container .orbit-prev {
        margin-left: -5%;
    }
    .orbit-container .orbit-next {
        margin-right: -5%;
    }

    .content-slider, .content-slider h3 {
      color: #fff;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:40.063em) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        padding: 2em 0;
      }
      .orbit-next, .orbit-prev {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        top: 11.5em;
      }
      button, .button.slider-btn {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 1.1em;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:741px) and (max-width:768px) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        top: 10em;
      }
      button, .button.slider-btn {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 1.1em;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:741px) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        top: 11em;
      }
      button, .button.slider-btn {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 1.5em;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:458px) and (max-width:600px) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        top: 9em;
      }
      button, .button.slider-btn {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 1.5em;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:458px) {
      .orbit-slides-container li div {
        top: 13.23em;
      }
      button, .button.slider-btn {
        font-size: 0.3rem;
        float: left !important;
        margin: -19px 0 12px;
      }
      .content-slider:after {
        margin-top: -65px !important;
      }
    }
```

JS

$(document).foundation('section').foundation('orbit', {
    timer_speed: 3000,
    animation_speed: 400,
    stack_on_small: false,
    navigation_arrows: true,
    slide_number: false,
    pause_on_hover: false,
    resume_on_mouseout: false,
    timer: false,
    variable_height: false,
  });

I have tried taking away the JS, the CSS nothing changes and I have tried copying pasting HTML directly from the Zurb Foundation Orbit webpage, no change, it is a Wordpress site so I took down all the plugins...no change? Kinda stuck, any ideas most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Orbit has been deprecated

Comment: Dam you Zurb, dam you!